# python path, can't use Django

Tags: python, django

i tried to install django, the installation was succeeded but i couldn't create new project. so i uninstalled and try to install again and this message showed up(didn't see it the first time):

> WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

so i look up online and people said used sys.path.append to fix but when i used it:

`sys.path.append('C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts')`

following message appeared

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.
> please help, i'm still new to Python and Django.

Comment: `\ ` are used to _escape_ stuff in strings in python, hence you need to escape them too: `sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts')`, note instead of using that just set your environment variables and add it to the path there

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Or use a raw string: `r"C:\Users..."` – however, modifying `sys.path` in the first place is a bad idea.

Comment: @AKX edited just before your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify `sys.path`. It'll lead to pain and heartbreak and hard-to-debug issues. Wherever you made that edit, get rid of it. (The `unicodeescape` error message is due to you not using a `r""` raw string, so `\Users` is interpreted as the start of an unicode sequence `sers` which is not a thing.) (In addition, editing `sys.path` within a Python script won't change your command prompt PATH, so there's no point in this anyway.)

Either:

- as the message said, add `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts` to your system PATH environment variable so you can use the globally-installed `django-admin`
- directly run `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\django-admin`
- or better yet, learn to create and use virtualenvs to keep your projects' dependencies separate; the virtualenv activation script will add the virtualenv's scripts directory to your path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' to you system path. You can do it through Windows configurations or from the command line :

```sh
setx path "%path%;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts"
```